# My app crashes when I press navigation item twice using map View

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

This is my onNavigationItemSelected method:

```
        }
```

Comment: logcat please ???

Comment: post your error log

Comment: Sorry guys i am new to this coding stuff formatting questions still gives me problems

Comment: there is something wrong in your xml. Can you show us your xml. @StanleyTutuDinala

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #11: Duplicate id 0x7f0e00e5, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
 int id = item.getItemId();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    if (id == R.id.nav_sports) {

        fragment = new FragmentOne();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_food) {
        fragment = new FragmentTwo();



    } else if (id == R.id.nav_security) {
        fragment = new FragmentThree();
     }
if (fragment != null) {
                fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, fragment).commit();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    FragmentManager fManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment frag = fManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (frag != null)
        fManager.beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
}
```

Keep this in your Fragment